# Problem with Commitizen Bump When I'm trying to generate my version with commitizen

Tags: python-3.11, changelog, commitizen

In my python project, I was asked to use commitizen. And then they asked me to generate and update the changelog.
I did it the first time and it worked.
But now I had a problem.
When I'm trying to generate my version with commitizen. When I use the command

```bash
cz bump 1.4.5 -ch
```

to generate the changelog together, it returns an error.

```bash
$ cz bump 1.4.5 -ch                                                                                                                

bump: version 1.4.3 → 1.4.5
tag to create: v.1.4.5

InvalidVersion GitTag('v.1.4.3', '3512322071378d56adf9a8a5f53', '2023-12-13')
InvalidVersion GitTag('v.1.4.1', 'e2fffe65272930fefd38aabbad5', '2023-11-13')
InvalidVersion GitTag('v.1.4.0', '211b6476cf7928b1ff8206a3305', '2023-11-13')
InvalidVersion GitTag('v.1.3.2', '8a26987fca341b0463b83d7181a', '2023-06-05')
InvalidVersion GitTag('v.1.3.0', '1e984e45a405501dd37b3cdb11f', '2023-05-26')
InvalidVersion GitTag('v.0.2.1', '66e7aa544fd88d3076ee192c872', '2023-03-01')
InvalidVersion GitTag('v.0.2.0', '81b36c82d3c624f18b5e202af09', '2023-02-28')
InvalidVersion GitTag('v.0.1.3', 'd734ac269f4cf287311595bb5e0', '2023-02-17')
InvalidVersion GitTag('v.0.1.2', '12856efa7d3d343859d7395e341', '2023-02-17')
InvalidVersion GitTag('v.0.1.0', '4ae0d11e08f1baea9aa5c56f865', '2023-02-17')
No tag found to do an incremental changelog
```

pyproject.toml file

```ini
[tool.commitizen]
name = "cz_conventional_commits"
version = "1.4.3"
tag_format = "v.$major.$minor.$patch$prerelease"
version_files = [
    "__version__.py",
    "pyproject.toml:version"
]
update_changelog_on_bump = true
changelog_incremental = true
```

pip freeze

```
argcomplete==3.1.6
asgiref==3.7.2
certifi==2023.11.17
cfgv==3.4.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
colorama==0.4.6
commitizen==3.13.0
decli==0.6.1
distlib==0.3.8
Django==5.0
django-auth-ldap==4.6.0
django-cors-headers==4.3.1
django-filter==23.5
django-ldap==0.0.8
django-simple-history==3.4.0
django-tables2==2.7.0
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
exceptiongroup==1.2.0
filelock==3.13.1
identify==2.5.33
idna==3.6
importlib-metadata==6.11.0
iniconfig==2.0.0
Jinja2==3.1.2
ldap3==2.9.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
nodeenv==1.8.0
openpyxl==3.1.2
packaging==23.2
platformdirs==4.1.0
pluggy==1.3.0
pre-commit==3.6.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.36
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
pyasn1==0.5.1
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pytest==7.4.3
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-ldap==3.4.4
PyYAML==6.0.1
questionary==2.0.1
requests==2.31.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
tablib==3.5.0
termcolor==2.4.0
toml==0.10.2
tomli==2.0.1
tomlkit==0.12.3
typing_extensions==4.9.0
urllib3==2.1.0
virtualenv==20.25.0
wcwidth==0.2.12
zipp==3.17.0
```

There is already a generated changelog file. Should I keep deleting and generating again?

I would like to know how to fix the command to generate the version tag, update the changelog so that I can prepare and send it to production.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the old version tag is not available in the machine where `cz bump` command is executed. In this case, you are trying to bump from `v.1.4.3` to `v.1.4.5`. So you need `v.1.4.3` to be present locally and the current branch should have tagged with `v.1.4.3` as the latest one.

Execute the following command to get all the tags

```
git fetch origin --tags
```

Once you get the tags execute the `cz bump`.

Answer (score 0):

It is funny but I have the same issue right now :). I was trying to apply for commitizen to an already existing project. I didn't have any tags... So I created a tag in Azure DevOps (for example v1.1.2). Then I added this tag info the changelog file (##v1.1.2). After that my CI pipeline sucessully bumped the version from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3 (I did a fix change).